# Trying to Build TreeView Query in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, xml

I have parent records in two tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.  Some records in `Table3` are children of `Table1`, and some are children of `Table2`.

I would like to build a query that I can use to populate a TreeView control with the data from `Table3` displaying either under `Table1` if it only has a parent in `Table1` and not `Table2`, or `Table2` if it has parent records in both `Table1` and `Table2`.

Is it possible that if the table3's column(Child) is only related to table 1 to show it under table 1 and not under table 2, but at the same time another (Child) has a parent in table 2 (which usually is the case) it will show under table 2 as its currently doing.

How can I output that in a query for a TreeView? I am assuming that I will have to program the output in C#, with 3 `FOR` loops.  In the second loop I can check if the column is grandchild or Child and make that as a second row or 2nd node of the TreeView, but I am having a problem building a query in SQL.

The query below shows all Parent, then child then grandchild, which is working, but what is desired is at times child takes place of a father.

```
DECLARE @x AS XML
SET @x =
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Table1.AssetSysID
        , Table1.Asset_ID
        , Table1.FromLR
        , Table1.Asset_ID + ', ' + Table1.[Desc2] AS GarndFather
        , Table2.ACISysID
        , Table2.PAssetSysID
        , Table2.FeatureName + ', ' + Table2.[DESC] AS Father
        , Table3.ITMSysID
        , Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] AS Child
    FROM Table1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AssetSysID = Table2.PAssetSysID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.AssetSysID = Table3.AssetSysID 
                                AND Table2.ACISysID = Table3.ACISysID
    WHERE (Table1.AssetType = @AssetType)
    FOR XML AUTO,root('xml')
);
```

I've modified the code above to reflect some changes:

```
DECLARE @x AS XML
SET @x =
(
    SELECT 
        Table1.AssetObjID AS "@AssetObjID"
        , Table1.Asset_ID AS "@Asset_ID"
        , Table1.FromLR AS "@FromLR"
        , Table1.AssetType + ', ' + Table1.StreetName + ', ' +  Table1.FromMunicNo   AS "@FirstRow"
        , (
            SELECT 
                Table2.ACIObjID AS "@ACIObjID"
                , Table2.PAssetObjID AS "@PAssetObjID"
                , Table2.Feature_ID + ', ' + Table2.FeatureName   AS "@ChildOfFirstRow"
                , (
                    SELECT 
                        Table3.ITMObjID AS "@ITMObjID"
                        , Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] AS "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                    FROM Table3
                    WHERE Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID 
                        AND Table2.ACIObjID = Table3.ACIObjID
                    FOR XML PATH('Table3'), TYPE
                    )
                FROM Table2
                WHERE 
                    Table1.AssetObjID = Table2.PAssetObjID
                FOR XML PATH('Table2'), TYPE
            )
        , (
            SELECT 
                Table3.ITMObjID AS "@ITMObjID"
                , Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] AS "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
            FROM Table3
            WHERE Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID 
                AND Table2.ACIObjID <> Table3.ACIObjID
            FOR XML PATH('Table3'), TYPE
        )
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Table1.AssetType = 'xxxx'
        FOR XML PATH('Table1'), root('xml')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an Idea from [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296869/tsql-query-for-tree-view-control-and-remove-empty-elements-from-an-xml-file) and a help from a team lead @ work

```
  select Table1.AssetObjID as "@AssetObjID",
           Table1.Asset_ID as "@Asset_ID",
           Table1.FromLR as "@FromLR",
           Table1.AssetType + ', ' + Table1.StreetName + ', ' +  Table1.FromMunicNo   as "@FirstRow",
           (
           select Table2.ACIObjID as "@ACIObjID",
                  Table2.PAssetObjID as "@PAssetObjID",
                  Table2.Feature_ID + ', ' + Table2.FeatureName   AS "@ChildOfFirstRow",
                  (
                  select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                         Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                  from Table3
                  where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                        Table2.ACIObjID = Table3.ACIObjID
                  for xml path('Table3'), type
                  )
           from Table2
           where Table1.AssetObjID = Table2.PAssetObjID
           for xml path('Table2'), type
           ),
(
           select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                         Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                  from Table3
                  where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                        Table2.ACIObjID <> Table3.ACIObjID
                  for xml path('Table3'), type
)
    from Table1
    where Table1.AssetType = 'xxxx'
    for xml path('Table1'), root('xml')
```

So It goes something like this:

```
<Table1 atrributes......... FirstRow=".........."/>
<Table2 atrributes......... ChildOfFirstRow="..........">
<Table3 atrributes......... GrandChildOfFirstRow=".........."/>
</Table2>
<Table3 atrributes......... GrandChildOfFirstRow="This GrandChild took the importance as equal to ChildOfFirstRow"/>
```